# Error converting data type varchar to bigint (with REPLACE)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've read a good number of posts with similar titles, but nothing answered my question.

I have a table with a column of population data.  The numbers in the column are comma-delimited (admittedly not a best practice, but that is beyond my control at this point).  I need to remove the commas in order to do some mathematical operations on the data, but I am getting the error mentioned in the title.  Below are the first few rows of data followed by the query that should return the data:

```
POPULATION  (No column name)
 7,859,000     7859000
   575,660      575660
   818,000      818000
 5,254,000     5254000
73,751,000    73751000
38,610,000    38610000

SELECT [population],
       CONVERT(bigint,REPLACE(cri.[population],',',''))
FROM Country_Region_Info AS cri
```

However, that query returns the error mentioned above.  The only way I could get it to work is by replacing bigint with numeric(20,0). I shouldn't have to do that. Nothing there is remotely close to the maximum value of bigint. There are no decimals. There are no leading or trailing spaces. What is going on here?

Another thing I don't understand: the bigint version of the query returns results if TOP 5 in included in the SELECT, but errors on TOP 6 or more.  On a different computer it works with TOP 2, but errors on TOP 3 or more.

Comment: This returns nothing? `select top 5 * from Country_Region_Info where population like '%[^0-9,]%'`

Comment: Not sure what is happening here - I cannot reproduce this, works just fine in my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance here :-(

Comment: I can almost guarantee that you have at least one row with bad data in the Population column. This is the price you pay for storing numbers as strings. You say it's beyond your control, but please fight back against this horrible design decision.

Comment: Check `SELECT *       
FROM Country_Region_Info AS cri
WHERE ISNUMERIC(CONVERT(bigint,REPLACE(cri.[population],',','')))<> 1`

Comment: In absence of an order by you are not going to get the same rows for server to server or query to query.  I suspect you have a big population you are not aware of.  Try order by len(POPULATION) desc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To investigate the problem, do this:

```
select *
from Country_Region_Info cri
where isnumeric(REPLACE(cri.[population],',','')) = 0 or cri.population like '%.%'
```

This will find the offensive numeric values.

To ignore these values:

```
SELECT [population],
       (case when isnumeric(REPLACE(cri.[population],',','')) = 1 and cri.population not like '%.%'
             then CONVERT(bigint,REPLACE(cri.[population],',',''))
        end)
FROM Country_Region_Info AS cri
```

You do still have the possibility of other numeric formats ("7e6"), but those probably are not in your data.

Comment: OK, thanks Gordon.  And likewise to Peter Radocchia. These queries returned two rows with bad data (19.082,000 and 10,797.000).  I shoulda' known.  Agreed, Aaron, I will look into changing this with the "powers  that be".

Comment: +1 but you could add a where clause here - currently you'll return rows with NULL in the second column, arguably quite useless depending on the goal of the query. :-)